# Import from parent directory for a test sub-directory without using packaging, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package, relative-import

TL;DR

For a fixed and unchangeable non-package directory structure like this:

```
some_dir/
    mod.py
    test/
        test_mod.py
        example_data.txt
```

what is a non-package way to enable `test_mod.py` to import from `mod.py`?

I am restricted to using Python 2.7 in this case.

I want to write a few tests for the functions in `mod.py`. I want to create a new directory `test` that sits alongside `mod.py` and inside it there is one test file `test/test_mod.py` which should import the functions from `mod.py` and test them.

Because of the well-known limitations of relative imports, which rely on package-based naming, you can't do this in the straightforward way. Yet, all advice on the topic suggests to build the script as a package and then use relative imports, which is impossible for my use case.

In my case, it is not allowable for `mod.py` to be built as a package and I cannot require users of `mod.py` to install it. They are instead free to merely check the file out from version control and just begin using it however they wish, and I am not able to change that circumstance.

Given this, what is a way to provide a simple, straightforward `test` *directory*?

Note: *not* just a test file that sits alongside `mod.py`, but an actual test directory since there will be other assets like test data that come with it, and the sub-directory organization is critical.

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but out of the dozen or so permutations of this question I've seen in my research before posting, I haven't seen a single one that addresses how to do this. They all say to use packaging, which is not a permissible option for my case.

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you can modify `PYTHONPATH` for your test runner . . .

Answer (score 1):

Based on @mgilson 's comment, I added a file `import_helper.py` to the test directory.

```
some_dir/
    mod.py
    test/
        test_mod.py
        import_helper.py
        example_data.txt
```

Here is the content of `import_helper.py`:

```
import sys as _sys
import os.path as _ospath 
import inspect as _inspect
from contextlib import contextmanager as _contextmanager

@_contextmanager
def enable_parent_import():
    path_appended = False
    try:
        current_file      = _inspect.getfile(_inspect.currentframe())
        current_directory = _ospath.dirname(_ospath.abspath(current_file))
        parent_directory  = _ospath.dirname(current_directory)
        _sys.path.insert(0, parent_directory)
        path_appended = True
        yield
    finally:
        if path_appended:
            _sys.path.pop(0)
```

and then in the import section of `test_mod.py`, prior to an attempt to import `mod.py`, I have added:

```
import unittest
from import_helper import enable_parent_import

with enable_parent_import():
    from mod import some_mod_function_to_test
```

It is unfortunate to need to manually mangle PYTHONPATH, but writing it as a context manager helps a little, and restores `sys.path` back to its original state prior to the parent directory modification.

In order for this solution to scale across multiple instances of this problem (say tomorrow I am asked to write a `widget.py` module for some unrelated tasks and it also cannot be distributed as a package), I have to replicate my helper function and ensure a copy of it is distributed with any tests, or I have to write that small utility as a package, ensure it gets globally installed across my user base, and then maintain it going forward.

When you manage a lot of Python code internal to a company, often one dysfunctional code distribution mode that occurs is that "installing" some Python code becomes equivalent to checking out the new version from version control.

Since the code is often extremely localized and specific to a small set of tasks for a small subset of a larger team, maintaining the overhead for sharing code via packaging (even if it is a better idea in general) will simply never happen.

As a result, I feel the use case I describe above is extremely common for real-world Python, and it would be nice if some import tools added this functionality for modifying PYTHONPATH, which some sensible default choices (like adding parent directory) being very easy.

That way you could rely on this at least being part of the standard library, and not needing to roll your own code and ensure it's either shipped with your tests or installed across your user base.